# Symfony: PHP class not found when loading Appbundle in Appkernel.php

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-routing

For some weird reason my App and ApiBundle Classes are not found during registerbundles()-function of Appkernel.php.

The classes are there and seeem to be correct and I cannot understand what the problem is.

Appkernel-entries:

```
    new Neulich\AppBundle\NeulichAppBundle(),
    new Neulich\ApiBundle\NeulichApiBundle(),
```

Neulich/src/AppBundle/NeulichAppBundle.php:

```
<?php

namespace Neulich\AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

/**
 * Class NeulichAppBundle
 *
 * @package Neulich\AppBundle
 */
class NeulichAppBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Please give me a hint, I've been trying for a long time now.

Thanks a lot.
Steffen

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache or reboot Symfony?

Comment: Hi thanks. clearing the cache didn't help. any other suggestion? THANKS - how to reboot symfony?

Comment: Don't mind, I think your path is incorrect. Should be `src/Neulich/AppBundle/NeulichAppBundle.php`.

Comment: Oh my god - too much working ;-) Sorry and thanks - probably would have taken forever to figure it out ;-)